# php "is_dir" file listings for Intranet site

Tags: php, directory, intranet

I'm creating a test file to get all files located in an intranet folder and simply put an icon image next to the file listed according to its extension. 
For some reason, the code is not pulling things correctly.

Here's a screen shot of the windows explorer view of the files in the directory.

[image]

And here is my code:

```
<?php

  $dir="file:///.....to_my_directory"; // Directory where files are stored

  if ($dir_list = opendir($dir)) {
     while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) != false) {

        if (is_dir($filename)) {
      $img = 'folder_img.jpg';
    } else {

      $filestuff = pathinfo($filename);
      $file_ext = isset($filestuff['extension']) ? $filestuff['extension'] : null;
      switch($file_ext) {
        case 'pdf':
        $img = 'pdf_img.jpg';
        break;

        case 'doc' || 'docx' || 'docm' || 'dotm' || 'dotx':
        $img = 'word_img.jpg';
        break;

        case 'xls' || 'xlsm' || 'xltx' || 'xlam' || 'xlsx' || 'xlm' || 'xlt' || 'xlsb':
        $img = 'excel_img.jpg';
        break;

        case 'txt':
        $img = 'txt_file_img.jpg';
        break;

        case NULL:
        $img = 'blank_file_img.jpg';
        break;
      }
   }



?>
<p><span><img src='<?php echo $img; ?>' height='23px;'/><a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename;?></a></span></p>


<?php
  }
    closedir($dir_list);
  }

?>
```

AND this is how it looks when I run it:

[image]

The problem is that certain extensions not listed are pulling the 'Microsoft WORD' icon.

The 'Access Database' file with extension '.mdb' is pulling a Word icon, the extension '.mdb_hcu' is also pulling a WORD icon.

How do I make it the BLANK file option (see my switch case where answer is NULL)

Also, how do I organize so that the folders are listed first and everything is in alphabetical order?

Is there a plugin that allows me to achieve this easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you can't list case values like this:

```
case 'doc' || 'docx' || 'docm' || 'dotm' || 'dotx':
```

That will get evaluated as one statement which will evaluate to true. Then the extension will compare to that result and unless the extension is `NULL`, the case will be true.

You need to list out each case option like so:

```
case 'doc':    //if
case 'docx':   //any
case 'docm':   //of
case 'dotm':   //these
case 'dotx':   //are true
               //this will run
    //set image
    break;     //up to this
```

If any of the cases are true (equal to the extension), the code inside the case will run until the `break` is hit.

Comment: How would I signify multiple options in one case then?

Comment: @bagofmilk: I was in the middle of typing out an example. It's up.

Comment: Awesome. Now the problem happens where It's not pulling the 'folder_img' icon next to folders - its using the default option. Did I setup my 'if-else' statement correctly?

Comment: Everything else looks fine from what I can tell. Another option is to remove the `case NULL:` (or `default:`, whichever you are using) and set `$img = 'blank_file_img.jpg';` before the switch statement. Then the switch will overwrite the image with the extension image. If you are still having trouble, edit your question and post your updated code along with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can you change `case NULL:` to `default:` and see if it works please?

`default:` means that if it doesn't match any of the "cases" then it will run the default one.

Thanks

:Edited Answer:

You need to change where you set `$img = 'folder_img.jpg'` as it sets it to word, then on the next 'while', it's not a dir, so doesn't change, but also doesn't match any case, so stays as it was on the last `while` - hope this makes sense!

Let me know if it works for you!

```
<?php

    $dir="."; // Directory where files are stored

    if ($dir_list = opendir($dir)) {
        while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) != false) {
            $img = 'folder_img.jpg';
            if (!is_dir($filename)) {
                $filestuff = pathinfo($filename);
                $file_ext = isset($filestuff['extension']) ? $filestuff['extension'] : null;
                switch($file_ext) {
                    case 'pdf':
                        $img = 'pdf_img.jpg';
                    break;

                    case 'doc':
                    case 'docx':
                    case 'docm':
                    case 'dotm':
                    case  'dotx':
                        $img = 'word_img.jpg';
                    break;

                    case 'xls':
                    case 'xlsm':
                    case 'xltx':
                    case 'xlam':
                    case 'xlsx':
                    case 'xlm':
                    case 'xlt':
                    case 'xlsb':
                        $img = 'excel_img.jpg';
                    break;

                    case 'txt':
                        $img = 'txt_file_img.jpg';
                    break;

                    default:
                        $img = 'blank_file_img.jpg';
                    break;
                }
            }
?>
<p><span><img src='<?php echo $img; ?>' height='23px;'/><a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename;?></a></span></p>


<?php
        }
    closedir($dir_list);
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is a good attempt. But then it doesn't place the 'folder' icon next to my folders - it instead uses the default option.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry - it looks like Jonathan has got it correct - the error seems to be switch's not supporting `||`